# check telephone number goes wrong

Tags: php, preg-replace

i use this to check if there is a 06 number in the string. the 06 number is always 10 numbers.

```
$string = "This is Henk 0612345678";

$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $string);

echo $number;
```

This is working good, but when the string is

```
$string = "This is 12Henk 0612345678";
```

The number is 120612345678
I dont want the 12 into it, but 12 is not always the same in the string.
How can i check only for a 10 digits number ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want `preg_match('/\b06\d{8}\b/', $string, $number)` and then `echo $number[0];`?

Comment: You want 2 times preg_match ?

Comment: Let me re-formulate: Are you looking for https://3v4l.org/EaHqR?

Comment: Thanks this is working!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Comments should not be used to provide answers. Either write a proper answer, wait for someone else to do so, or vote to close.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Rather than replacing everything that's *not* what you want, try searching for what you *do* want with [preg_match](https://php.net/preg_match).

That makes it a lot easier to be specific:

- The number always starts `06`, so you can hard-code that in your regex
- That's followed by exactly 8 more digits, which you can specify as `[0-9]{8}` or `\d{8}` ("d" for "digit")
- To avoid matching *longer* numbers, you can surround that with `\b` for "word break"

Put it together, and you get:

```php
preg_match('/\b06\d{8}\b/', $string, $matched_parts);
```

This doesn't change `$string`, but gives you an array in `$matched_parts` containing the matched parts; see the preg_match documentation for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I am thoroughly baffled by the downvotes here. Do you actually think it's the _wrong_ answer - if so, in what way? Or just that I shouldn't have answered at all - but then why are there no "Close" votes on the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```
/([ \w]+)(06[0-9.+]{8})/
```

the 1st () is the entire String before the 06 and the 2nd() is the Number starting with 06 and 8 digits.

The solution does not cover the case where a 06 comes before the number sequence

Comment: Is not working, the string is now: Live - DJ Henkie Uio180 reactie 0612345678
When i use your preg_match im getting Ive as output.